# HTTP Post using JSON for UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, http-post

I am attempting to leverage http POST to send a JSON object (UIImage is included in POST). Below is the code I am currently using, but for some reason the server is not receiving the POST. Can anyone provide insight as to why this may not be working?

```
NSString *userString = [[NSString alloc]init];
userString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"userId"];

//convert image to nsdata object
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, .9);

NSLog(@"User id is:%@", userString);
NSLog(@"The tag string:%@", myTagString);
NSLog(@"the question string is:%@", myQuestionString);
NSLog(@"the image data is:%@", imageData);
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"category", @"question", @"latitude",  @"longitude", @"user_id", @"image",nil];

NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myTagString, myQuestionString, @"0.0", @"0.0",  userString, imageData, nil];
NSDictionary *theRequestDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://theserver.com/query"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0f];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[theRequest setValue:@"application/json-rpc" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
NSString *theBodyString = [[NSString alloc]init];
theBodyString = [[CJSONSerializer serializer] serializeDictionary:theRequestDictionary];
NSLog(@"body string: %@", theBodyString);
NSData *theBodyData = [theBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"body data: %@", theBodyData);
[theRequest setHTTPBody:theBodyData];

NSURLResponse *theResponse = NULL;
NSError *theError = NULL;
NSData *theResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&theResponse error:&theError];
NSString *theResponseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:theResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(@"the response string:%@", theResponseString);
NSDictionary *theResponseDictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserialize:theResponseData error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", theResponseDictionary);
```

This is my first post in a forum so I apologize if some of the formatting is wrong. Feel free to critique it so I can submit better posts in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code in this project of mine in Github http://akos.ma/7qp where the Wrapper class sets a couple of headers in the request, so that the server can process the binary data being uploaded. Look at the uploadData:toUrl: method in line 118, which sets the required content type headers.